# Ansibe Jinja2 Filter

Tags: list, filter, ansible, jinja2

I want to apply filter to the following log file. But I keep missing something

**task.yml**

```
-   ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: true
    invocation:
        module_args:
            policy_package: Package1
            version: null
            wait_for_task: true
            wait_for_task_timeout: 30
    item: PackageItem1
    msg: Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-a422-xxxxxxxxx
        failed. Look at the logs for more details
-   ansible_loop_var: item
    changed: false
    failed: true
    invocation:
        module_args:
            policy_package: Package2
            version: null
            wait_for_task: true
            wait_for_task_timeout: 30
    item: PackageItem2
    msg: Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-a6c4-xxxxxxxx
        failed. Look at the logs for more details
```

Here is my playbook
**filter.yml**

```
---
- name: sftp-domain
  hosts: check_point
  connection: httpapi
  gather_facts: False
  vars_files:
    - 'credentials/my_var.yml'
    - 'credentials/login.yml'

  tasks:
  - name: set-details
    set_fact:
      filter: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp/task.yml') }}"

  - name: create list to loop through
    set_fact:
      new_list: "{{ filter | map(attribute='msg') | flatten }}"

  - name: copy-file-to-log
    local_action:
      module: copy
      content: "{{  new_list | to_nice_yaml }}"
      dest: tmp/task2.yml
```

I get an error message saying

```
PLAY [sftp-domain] *******************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set-details] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [checkpoint]

TASK [create list to loop through] ***************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [checkpoint]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'msg'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/tdeveu0/project/fwp_automation/filter.yml': line 15, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: create list to loop through\n    ^ here\n"}
```

**Here is actually the result I want after applying filter**

```
- msg: Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-a6c4-xxxxxxxx
        failed. Look at the logs for more details

- msg: Task Verify policy operation with task id 01234567-89ab-cdef-a422-xxxxxxxxx
        failed. Look at the logs for more details
```

I want to get only the list of all the 'msg'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the filter *from_yaml*

```yaml
  - name: set-details
    set_fact:
      filter: "{{ lookup('file', 'tmp/task.yml')|from_yaml }}"
```

---

Let's take a simplified file to show the problem, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat task.yml
- a: 1
  b: 2
- a: 3
  b: 4
```

When you read the file into the variable the result is AnsibleUnsafeText, not a list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        filter: "{{ lookup('file', 'task.yml') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ filter|type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        var: filter.0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: AnsibleUnsafeText
  filter.0: '-'
```

The first item of the text is the dash '-'.

---

Use filter *from_yaml* to get the list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        filter: "{{ lookup('file', 'task.yml')|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ filter|type_debug }}"
    - debug:
        var: filter.0
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: list
  filter.0:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```